# Building druid got stuck and does not move forward

Tags: docker, druid

I am trying to build **druid** using the docker file provided on the [pulsarIO/dockerfiles](https://github.com/pulsarIO/docker-files/tree/master/pulsarReporting/druid)

But it does not gets build fully and gets stuck at some point:

The Stack looks like this :

```
shivansh@localhost:~/Documents/Huawei/pulsar/docker-files/pulsarReporting/druid$ sudo sh build
Sending build context to Docker daemon 35.33 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
 ---> 45e5f47e0036
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Xu,Xin <xinxu1@ebay.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 46d0ac73c2ed
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7ecac41ee372
Step 4 : RUN apt-get install -y vim less net-tools inetutils-ping curl git telnet nmap socat dnsutils netcat tree htop unzip sudo software-properties-common
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be238924e32a
Step 5 : RUN echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java.list &&     apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886 &&     apt-get update &&     echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections &&     apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7b462d5c7b60
Step 6 : RUN wget -q -O - http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz | tar -xzf - -C /usr/local       && ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.5 /usr/local/apache-maven       && ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin/mvn
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8d93a2bebc76
Step 7 : RUN mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=io.druid:druid-services:0.7.3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1e3fccd70f5b
Step 8 : RUN curl http://static.druid.io/artifacts/releases/druid-0.7.3-bin.tar.gz | tar xz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73d092b0fc55
Step 9 : RUN mv druid-0.7.3 druid-services
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 278eb7e7f30c
Step 10 : RUN apt-get install -y mysql-server &&     sed -i 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9864be2ef7ce
Step 11 : ADD config druid-services/config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4f3d4b4dd1d7
Step 12 : ADD ./mysql.ddl mysql.ddl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 51b798fa62da
Step 13 : RUN mysqld_safe & mysqladmin --wait=5 ping &&     mysql < mysql.ddl &&     mysqladmin shutdown
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f7ddfd9fbd3e
Step 14 : WORKDIR /druid-services
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc01a554687d
Step 15 : RUN java -classpath "config/_common:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main tools pull-deps
 ---> Running in d8a09c205f3d
Oct 25, 2016 7:23:31 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
```

I cannot understand exactly what the problem is ! And If i try to run the

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

command to see the running containers I cannot see the druid one there !

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: How much time did you let it run? it was stuck on my laptop for a while but I left it on for a few hours and when I came back it was successfully built.